# Magento 2 - Mutiselect Attribute - Filter not working

Tags: magento2

We created a product and configured with multiselect attribute.

[image]

Customer view it displays like below

[image]

If customer choose either 'Orange' or 'Red', it filters the product correctly and displays.

If customer choose both 'orange' & 'red' means, getting "We can't find products matching the selection."